# Unable to get product attribute value store wise,

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have a magento1.x product attribute (its scope is store, and admin site defines default and store wise attribute value different)

I am trying to get its value but every time i got default store value

My collection query

```
$productCollections = $productCollection->joinAttribute('visibility','catalog_product/visibility','entity_id',null,'inner',$store->getId())->joinAttribute('status','catalog_product/status','entity_id',null,'inner',$store->getId());
```

Want get store wise value for a product attribute

Comment: Have you tried to pass static value for **`store id`**? I mean 1 or 2 instead of $store->getId().

Comment: Yes i did it, i pass static value